# Continuity of a function in cofinite topological space

Tags: general-topology

Consider the cofinite topology $\tau_f$ on $\mathbb{R}$. Is the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=x^3-4x+1$ continuous?

Should I show that $f$ is one-to one? and then to show that inverse image of every closed set is closed?

Answer (score 4):

Here's what you can do :

1. For any $a\in \mathbb{R}$, $f^{-1}(\{a\})$ is finite (because it is the solution set of some polynomial equation)
2. For any $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathbb{R}\setminus A$ is finite,
   $$
   \mathbb{R}\setminus f^{-1}(A) = f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}\setminus A) = \cup_{a \in \mathbb{R}\setminus A} f^{-1}(\{a\})
   $$

Conclude that, if $A$ is open, then $f^{-1}(A)$ is open.